# Updating 3D text each frame crashes my game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a game in unity 5 similar to the old school mario party games. I am running into an issue with my dice code where it causes unity to crash when i run the game. I want my code to constantly change the number that appears on the dice block. Example (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7suvd4UA6cU) just pay attention to the numbers on the dice.
I have tried two different ways to code this, but neither are working for me.

Example 1:

```
void Update () {
    while (Clicked == false)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        {
            numberText.text = i.ToString();

        }
    }
}
```

Example 2:

```
void Update () {
    while (Clicked == false)
    {
        AutoIncrement();
    }
}
void AutoIncrement()
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
    {
        numberText.text = i.ToString();

    }
}
```

I know these are basically the same but i figured i'd try it anyway.
Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am fairly new to unity and c#.

Comment: You’re running that code forever. There’s no coming out of it to let any other code run. If you run it while debugging you’ll see. But crash? Hang would be more logical.

Comment: It completely freezes unity and I have to kill it from task manager, would you not call that a crash?

Comment: No, that’s a freeze as you say. A crash is a crash. This is an important difference. Anyway, it’s an eternal loop. That’s why it hangs. Don’t loop, update the number and return.

Comment: That's not my entire code. this is just the part that I am getting caught up on. I have a function that changes "Clicked" to true. I only did it this way because I wanted it to repeat until the user clicked the dice block. Would you like to see my full code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) to do that

```
IEnumerator DiceNumberManager(){
    int i = 1;
    while (true){
        numberText.text = i.ToString();
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
        i++;
        if (i>10) i=1;
    }
}
```

Start it when you want it to change numbers and stop it when you want it to stop with:

[StartCoroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html) & 
[StopCoroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StopCoroutine.html)

Comment: I'm glad, I edited it to be able to repeat from 1 after it gets to 10